# Startup-Sound stops playback before end in Phonegap 2.2.0 Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, media-player, android-mediaplayer

In my Phonegap 2.2.0 Android app I want to play a sound at startup, while the splashscreen is shown, hiding the webview in the background, where the rest of the magic happens - but needs its time to prepare itself...
so I use my onCretae like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 4000);

    // play startup sound
    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, R.raw.startup);

    mp.start();
}
```

works nice - but not perfect: Some thing (maybe the webview itself?) is stoppig the playback of my startup sound. it stops before it was played till the end.
I read about overriding the onComplete-method of the mediaplayer instance because there is a [300mx gap issue in Android MediaPlayer Class](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Ciiu1C-_EmE) when releasing itself but this didn't work out and seems not to be true (I added 1s silence at the end of the audiofile - no difference).
So how could I make my startup sound play fully? thnx!